# drop duplicates in a python dataframe for multiple columns not containing a particular string in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I would like to drop duplicates confined to C2 and C3 columns. However, now when keeping the row for the duplicates, the row which starts with "zx" in column C4 should be given priority.  For example:  consider the row 0 and 1 (referring to C1 column),  the row "0" stays in the output since it contains "zx" but  C4 is dropped. Also, when both the duplicates contain the same "zx" for example  row 6 and 7 anyone can be dropped . However, when duplicate rows(for column C2 and C3) contain different "zx" , both should stay for example: 
row: 8 and 9.

Input :

```
C1  C2   C3   C4
0   AB   Dat  zx101
1   AB   Dat  tp102
2   CD   CR   zx1032
3   CD   CR   lx1032
4   EF   KLM  2x501
5   EF   KLM  2x501
6   HI   NOP  zx707
7   HI   NOP  zx707
8   PL   TIP  zx303
9   PL   TIP  zx304
```

Output:

```
C1  C2   C3   C4
0   AB   Dat  zx101
2   CD   CR   zx1032
4   EF   KLM  2x501
6   HI   NOP  zx707
8   PL   TIP  zx303
9   PL   IPT  2x304
```

Comment: show what you've tried. Stack overflow isn't a coding. Post your code, please. Look at [ask] and how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

a natural way is to

- first **sort** your data so that the observation you want to keep is always the first for each duplicate group
- then use `drop_duplicates( keep = 'first')`